# Assign different jobs to different users properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am building a peer marking system. I want the system auto assign 2 different submissions to the students to mark. So each student could be assigned two different submissions to mark, and two of these submissions do not belong to himself/herself. A submission can be only assigned to 2 different students.
(A submission can be only assigned two times)

I use the Submission table to get the user_id. Model AssignSubmission has many Submission. Submission belongTo AssignSubmission. Submission table saves the submissions that student submits.

```
public function handle(){
                    $students = Submission::all();
                    foreach ($students as $student) {

                        $jobs = Submission::all()->shuffle();

                        $i = 0;

                        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
                            if (($job->user_id !== $student->user_id) && ($i<2) ) {
                                $i++;
                                $newjob = New AssignSubmission;

                                $newjob->submission_id = $job->id;
                                $newjob->user_id = $student->user_id;
                                $newjob->save();

                               }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

My question is how to restrict the submission form saving more than 2 times. I ONLY want the one submission assigns to two different students.

Here is one of the result.
[image]
Here is the result I expect
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort this out myself.
If there are 15 students, then there are 15 assignments, and it is very simple to guarantee that they will not get their homework. As long as they are arranged in order, the first classmate takes the second place and the second place takes the third place. . ... Finally take the first place. However, this has limitations, and I can guess who I will get. Then it becomes a variable

```
public function handle()
{
  $students = Submission::orderBy('user_id','asc')->get(['user_id','id']);
  $word=$students->pluck('id')->toArray();
  $count_student =count($students);
  $random_num = mt_rand(1,$count_student-1);
  $word_num= 2;//How many jobs per person  

  $students->map(function($student,$k)use($word,$count_student,$random_num,$word_num){
  $arr=[];// save submission id
  for ($for_i=0;$for_i<$word_num;$for_i++){
  $index = $k+$random_num+$for_i;
  if(!isset($word[$index]))
  {
   $index-=$count_student;
  }
   $arr[]=$word[$index];
   }
   $student->homeworks = $arr;

   $newjob = New AssignSubmission;
   $newjob->submission_id = $student->homeworks[0];
   $newjob->user_id = $student->user_id;
   $newjob->save();
   $newjob = New AssignSubmission;
   $newjob->submission_id = $student->homeworks[1];
   $newjob->user_id = $student->user_id;
   $newjob->save();

   });
```